# aptana 3 code completion doesn't remove typed letters

Tags: aptana3

guys have you ever encountered this problem in Aptana 3. say when I type in "t" in the editor the code completion will pop a suggestion list containing "text/javascript" at the top of the list, then I click the "enter" key to choose the suggestion. But it doesn't remove what I typed before namely the "t", and shows "ttext/javascript". Is this a bug or just I mis-configure it?